# Where is "sprite" defined?

Tags: javascript, html, undefined, sprite, typeerror

Where exactly in this fiddle: (http://jsfiddle.net/wXs9J/) is "sprite" defined? I'm using the same type of animation in my own program but I get the line: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stateAnimations' of undefined" at the lines:

```
function drawSprite(sprite) {
    ctx.drawImage(
    sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].tileset.image, 
    sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].frames[sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].currentFrame].split(',')[0] * sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].tileset.tileWidth,
    sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].frames[sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].currentFrame].split(',')[1] * sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].tileset.tileHeight,
    sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].tileset.tileWidth,
    sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].tileset.tileHeight,
    Math.round(sprite.positionX),
    Math.round(sprite.positionY),
    sprite.width,
    sprite.height
);
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object

```
var player = new Sprite({
    'left': spriteLeftAnim,
    'right': spriteRightAnim
}, 'right', canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 44, 108, 100);
```

is passed in as a parameter named `sprite` in the method `render()`

`player` is defined in a global scope in the same file.

Comment: +1 cause You beat me to it :)
It's line 107 in the fiddle if that helps anyone.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but after reading this I don't think this is where the problem is.. in this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/dqDAv/ ) I'm getting an error, and I have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: You did not include the `player=` in the fiddle. Also, there is no object called `currentState`

Answer (score 0):

The Sprite consructor is on line 28
A sprite (called player) is created on line 72
This sprite is passed to drawSprite on line 107

Comment: doh! beaten to it by @karthikr